# Website won't load in Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: htaccess, joomla, firefox, user-agent

After the latest version of Firefox came out, I've been having problems with my website. The site is: http://mojheroj.com It works fine in all other browsers, as well as older versions of Firefox and Firefox 4.0 beta 7, but it just won't load in 3.6.13. When I try, all I get is a blank page. I don't even get an error.

At first I thought it might be a problem with the program, so I tried clearing the cache, reinstalling, opening the page in safe-mode, but nothing helped. After checking with some friends, they seem to have the same problem.

The website is done in Joomla, with some jQuery. To make things even weirder, I can access the administrator part of the site through Firefox just fine.

Also, when I change the browser's user agent, Firefox can open my page. So, I'm guessing that's where the problem lies, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried checking Joomla's .htaccess file, but the USER_AGENT property isn't defined at all. Could someone please help me how I could fix this? I really need the website to work in Firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: I've just tried the site and I can't see it at all, let along in FF 3.6.13

Answer (score 1):

Check apache's error log. When the user agent is FF 3.6.13, it's causing an internal server error (response code 500). But this could be from any number of factors, so there's no way for us to diagnose the problem without more information.